# Неправильно рассчитывается угол между векторами

Tags: c#, векторы

Нужно что бы картинка в битмапе разворачивалась в сторону мышки.
Угол рассчитываю так -

```
 m.RotateAt( (float) (Math.Atan2(MousVect.X -14, MousVect.Y ) * (180 / Math.PI))+ 90,new Point(601,578) );
 Gr.Transform = m;
 Gr.DrawImage(car, new Point(600-17,600-40));
```

Где MousVect X,Y - значения вектора с началом в середине картинки и концом в текущих координатах мышки.
Вектор картинки всегда равен 14,0.
Проблема в том,что в промежутке 0 - 180 градусов и 0 - (-180) градусов картинка направлена в обратную сторону от мыши. Где я сделал ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Аргументы atan2 идут в порядке (y,x), а у вас наоборот
*(Вы пытаетесь компенсировать это добавлением 90 градусов)*

Comment: Исправил,но картинка разворачивается в обратном от координат стрелки навравлении.
P.S. Компенсировал это добавлением 180 градусов,теперь все идеально. Спасибо.

Comment: @Alexey: Вам всего ли шь нужно было добавить `-`к значению.

Comment: @LLENN Нет,при  -  отображалось неправильно. Поставит его было первым что я попробовал

Comment: минус значение угла - это отражение относительно оси OX, а вам потребовалось отражение относительно центра координат, оно действительно соответствует  +180 градусов, можно также изменить знаки у обоих аргументов atan2